# h:commandButton not working inside h:dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, commandbutton, commandlink

I am trying to execute an `action` through `commandButton` inside a `dataTable`, but the `action` is not invoked when the `commandButton` is placed inside the datatable as shown below

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
        <h:column>
            <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

When I move the `commandButton` out of `dataTable`, the `action` is successfully executed. What is the problem when `commandButton` is inside datatable? The `commandLink` has the same problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This problem can happen when the list behind `#{bean.list}` is **not** exactly the same during the HTTP request of processing the form submit as it was during the request of displaying the form. JSF will namely re-iterate over the list to locate the button pressed and invoke its action.

If the bean is request scoped and the list is not repopulated during bean's (post)construction, or the list's population depends on a request scoped variable which was lost during the form submit, then JSF will retrieve an empty or a completely different list while processing the form submit and thus won't be able to locate the button pressed and won't invoke any action.

The best fix is to put the bean in the view scope and ensuring that you're loading the data model the proper way.

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private List<Item> list;

    @EJB
    private ItemService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list = service.list();
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked) - point 4
- [Benefits and pitfalls of `@ViewScoped`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html)

Comment: I was using Spring Web Flow and had the "list" set on the view render  to [code]flashScope.myList[/code]  Thanks to this comment I thought to change it to [code]viewScope.myList[/code] and it worked great.  Thanks!