# JSF Output not coming as expected by using commandLink, ViewScope in dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, datatable, javabeans

Below are the files I have.

### manageStaff.xhtml

```
<h:dataTable var="c" value="#{newStaffMemberServiceBean.newStaffMemberDataBeanList}"
             styleClass="order-table"
             headerClass="order-table-header"
             rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
             border="1" id="staffListDataTable" width="100%">

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            Staff Member Name
    </f:facet>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink action="viewStaffMemberProfileData" value="#{c.firstName}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{newStaffMemberServiceBean.userId}" value="XXXYYYZZZZ"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

### viewStaffMemberProfileData.xhtml

```
 My Name is -<h:outputText value="#{newStaffMemberServiceBean.userId}" />-
```

### NewStaffMemberServiceBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "newStaffMemberServiceBean")
//@RequestScoped
@ViewScoped
//@SessionScoped
public class NewStaffMemberServiceBean {

    private String userId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
```

In output what I get is in below format

```
Staff Member Name
++++++++++++++++++

Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
.
.
.
.
```

On Clicking `Name 1`, I get re-directed to `viewStaffMemberProfileData.xhtml`.

***BUT*** problems are

1. To get re-directed on `viewStaffMemberProfileData.xhtml` page, I have to click link (Name 1, Name 2, etc) twice :(
2. When I get re-directed to `viewStaffMemberProfileData.xhtml` I only see output as

   `My Name is --`

   What I want is `My Name is -XXXYYYZZZZ-`.

Suggest me where I am going wrong.

### NOTE

I have all beans in ***`ViewScope`***.

### Update 1

@prajeeshkumar

Getter setter are as below

```
    public List<NewStaffMemberDataBean> getNewStaffMemberDataBeanList() {
    return newStaffMemberDataBeanList;
    }

    public void setNewStaffMemberDataBeanList(List<NewStaffMemberDataBean> newStaffMemberDataBeanList) {
    this.newStaffMemberDataBeanList = newStaffMemberDataBeanList;
    }
```

Comment: The same question again ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653078/hcommandlink-not-working-inside-datatable/9653541

Comment: what is the getter/setter for the property `newStaffMemberDataBeanList` ?

Comment: @prajeeshkumar : ***READ AGAIN*** They are NOT same question. Look at the two problems that I listed. Now I am able to get re-directed to new page by using `ViewScope`.

Comment: @prajeeshkumar : For getter setter, see **Update 1**

Comment: Is putting the id in session scope not an option for you?

Comment: DONT SHOUT at us. They are basically the same question.

Comment: It would help if you edit your question to more adequately indicate the differences with your previous question.

Comment: @TimPost : In earlier question, h:commandLink was not working. In this question it is working but (1) I have to click twice to get re-directed to another page (2) & output is not coming as expected .. Problem 1 is solved and I am still looking into second question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is the view scope of the newStaffMemberServiceBean  , its being destroyed and created again... so the value is being nullified... here an alternative solution:

haven't tried this one, But worth trying

change

```
<h:commandLink action="viewStaffMemberProfileData" value="#{c.firstName}">
     <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{newStaffMemberServiceBean.userId}" value="XXXYYYZZZZ"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

into

```
<h:link value="#{c.firstName}" outcome="nameOfXhtmlGoesHere">
     <f:param name="id" value="XXXYYYZZZZ" />
</h:link>
```

and in viewStaffMemberProfileData.xhtml

add this before the `<h:head>`

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{newStaffMemberServiceBean.userId}" />
</f:metadata>
```

you can also add `<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{newStaffMemberServiceBean.init}" />` to the `f:metadata` in order to do some init...

based on this [BalusC great article - Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

**OR**

you can turn the scope of newStaffMemberServiceBean into SessionScope...

Comment: this is working ***BUT*** I am getting `?id=XXXYYYZZZZ` in URL which is ***BAD*** :( Any OTHER solution?

Comment: Also any idea why on first click same page is shown & on second click the page get re-directed to the page requested??

Comment: I think I will have to use `Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();` here. Your thoughts on it??

Comment: haven't worked with Flash , but... http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-using-flash-scope/ looks like a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

If you have `newStaffMemberServiceBean` in view scope, then when you are going to a different page (view) will that bean be available in that scope ? I mean `manageStaff.xhtml` will have one instance and `viewStaffMemberProfileData.xhtml` will have another one.  Your solution here will be using the session scope or using the `h:link` or `h:outputLink`

Comment: why to bring id in session scope what it will be for one request only?